# Split string por conjuntos de letra com números

Tags: php, string

Tenho a seguinte string num determinado array:

```
[est] => INA1C4A1
```

preciso de dividir em conjuntos:

```
 [0] => Array
     (
        [mov] => IN
        [seq] => Array
                (
                   [0] => A1
                   [1] => C4
                   [2] => A1
                )
```

*its easy!*, mas o problema é que o "A1" pode ser "A11", assim pensei dividir em conjuntos até aparecer o primeiro caracter:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr_res);$i++){
    $aux[$i][mov] =  substr($arr_res[$i][cod], 0, 2);
    $aux_mov =  substr($arr_res[$i][codigo], 2, strlen($arr_res[$i][codigo])-1);

    $aux[$i][seq] = preg_split('/(?=[0-9]+)/',$aux_mov,3);
}
```

o resultado não é o esperado:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [mov] => IN
            [seq] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => 1C
                    [2] => 4A1
                )
```

É este o problema **'/(?=[0-9]+)/'**?

Comment: O "IN" (mov) é o quê? Como é para extrair?

Comment: @Miguel O "IN" já está extraído em " $aux[$i][mov] =  substr($arr_res[$i][cod], 0, 2); " a minha questão é " preg_split "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para capturar 'individualmente' esses conjuntos não quebre (split) a string, faça a captura usando `preg_match_all()` assim você define quais partes vai pegar da string.

`preg_split()` vai dividir a string em partes iguais conforme o delimitador, o que não é muito adequado para essa situação.

`[A-Z]\d{1,2}` significa caputra **uma** letra maiuscula entre A e Z seguida de **um** ou até no máximo **dois** digitos (0-9)

Fique atento que caso o conjunto tenha 3 ou mais caracteres apenas os dois primeiros serão casados, os demais serão descartados.

[Exemplo ideone](http://ideone.com/OzzJ69)

```
$str = 'INA1C4A1';

preg_match_all('/[A-Z]\d{1,2}/', $str, $m);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($m);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => C4
            [2] => A1
        )

)
```

Comment: Obrigado, não estava no caminho certo. Agora entendo.